# How to know whether Email delivery or not?

Tags: apex, trigger, email, class

i have requirement.To track the Email was send or not?

if once receive email.the status will changed?

Any apex code for this above condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the email status in email logs.Below are the steps that you can follow

- From Setup, enter Email Log Files in the Quick Find box, then select
  Email Log Files.
- Click Request an Email Log.
- Optionally, you can filter an email log to only include rows where a
  specific domain name or email address appears in a field, such as
  Recipient or Message ID Header. To enter more than one filter term,
  separate each value with a comma. If you leave this field blank, the
  log is not filtered and all email addresses are returned within the
  specified time range.
- Enter the email addresses that you want to receive notification when
  the email log request is complete. Separate each email address with a
  comma.

Below is the link that help you to track the email log status:

**https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs_format.htm&type=0**

Let me know if it helps.